# How to monitor any input and output of a process

Tags: macos, profiling, nfs, dtrace

There is the following process: NetAuthSysAgent which calls/create repeatedly the process mount_nfs of a non-existing NFS share. I have a hunch that these calls are triggered by another process which gives the instruction.

Therefore I would like to profile the NetAuthSysAgent, perhaps using dtrace, and see all inputs (like IPC incl. signals, queues, files, sockets, etc.) for this process and also verify all read files or memory area before it calls the mount_nfs process.

How can I do that? Is dtrace suitable and if yes how?

Any help is welcome. Even if it would only apply/work on FreeBSD or Solaris, I could try to adapt it myself to OS X.

**Update:**
I have been using the following commands yet, but I have covered only the file part:

```
dtrace -q -n syscall::open:entry'{ printf("%-16s %-16s\n",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

the above command gave me the processes and opened files.

```
opensnoop -va -n NetAuthSysAgent
```

the above command is a script calling DTrace stuffs, it is more or less the same as the previous command but it is filtered by the process NetAuthSysAgent and provides a few more information (e.g. UID, PID, FD, etc.)